# How far is it to extend the results of SGA III Exp. VIB from group schemes to group spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes, algebraic-spaces

How far is it to extend the results of SGA III Exp. VIB from group schemes to group spaces?
In particular, does Corollary 4.4 from SGA III Exp. VIB hold for G/S being merely a group space? Here the base $S$ is still a scheme.

Is there any reference for group spaces? I checked stack project, but the section 'properties of group algebraic spaces' from Chapter "groupoids in alg. sp." is less than 1 page.  Raynaud's IHES paper contains a few pages.

To be more precise, I would like to know if the following is ture:

Let $G/S$ be group space locally of finite presentation with $S$ a trait (to make it easier), let $s,t$ be the closed point and generic point of $S$ respectively. Suppose $G_s$ and $G_t$ are smooth over $k(s)$ and $k(t)$ respectively, and $\mathrm{dim}G_s=\mathrm{dim}G_t$. 
Then the functor $G^0$ (defined as in SGA III Exp. VI B Def. 3.1) is represented by a smooth group scheme over $S$.

Comment: Which aspect of Corollary 4.4 are you interested in for group algebraic spaces? Could you formulate a precise statement that you would like to have for your application? This would help in trying to give a useful answer.

Comment: @ Kestutis, done, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the proof of the key input from EGA (namely IV$_4$, 15.6.7) for algebraic spaces? Also, what exactly is your motivation?  Is it related to Picard functors?

Comment: I am trying, but as you know, the style of EGA and SGA is like the proof of some theorem is based on dozens of theorem before. So I don't feel confident with adopting the proofs of SGA III Exp. VIB for algebraic spaces.   And yes, my question is related to Picard functor for algebraic sapces over schemes

Comment: Indeed, I am reading  EGA IV4, 15.6.7 right now.

Comment: @Heer: You may know this already, but once you show that $G^0$ is an open subalgebraic space of $G$, all that remains to do is to prove that $G^0$ is separated (due to Thm. 4.B in Anantharaman's "Schemas en groupes..."). Here's how to show that $G^0 \subset G$ is an open subspace: it is a subsheaf and, since it is defined by a subspace of $|G|$, it suffices to show that that subspace is open; moreover, an fppf sheaf is an algebraic space if it is so etale (or fppf) locally, so wlog work etale locally on $S$ to lift the identity section of $G$ to a Noeth. $G$-scheme $U$ that is $G$-etale...

Comment: ... Now use the EGA result to form $U^0$ along that section, and then map $U^0$ back to $G$ to get an open subset $Y$ of $|G|$ contained in the subset $X$ defining $G^0$. To then show openness of $X$, work fiberwise to prove that $X$ is the (open since $Y$ is) image of $Y \times Y$ under the multiplication map on $G$. This proves that $G^0$ is an algebraic space. I am not sure whether $G^0$ automatically separated, but $G$ itself is certainly not: there are many counterexamples with Picard functors of relative curves in Ch. 9 of the book "Neron models".

Comment: @Kestutis: Great! Thanks! I will think about the separateness

Comment: Dear Heer, do you in fact assume that $G$ is smooth over $S$? If I'm not mistaken, with your assumptions it could be that $G=G_s\amalg G_t$ mapping to $S$ in the natural way, which I doubt you want to consider.

Comment: Maybe could you have a look at Lemma 4.2.8 in the paper S. Brochard, Foncteur de Picard d’un champ algébrique, Math. Ann. 2009. Also note that this has been extended to alg. stacks in an Erratum to the paper, available on the author's webpage.

Comment: @Matthieu Romagny: no, doesn't my condition imply the condition (ii) of sga3 exp.viB Cor.4.4? I'm confused, in your example, what's the unit section?

Comment: the reference is very useful, thanks @Matthieu

Comment: You're perfectly right that the assumptions of condition (ii) of sga3 exp.viB Cor.4.4 are met. The point I was worried about is whether (ii) should imply (i) in loc. cit., and it is quite striking that for reduced $S$ (as in your case) this implication holds. Apologies!